VB2022 program does not start properly
VB2022 starting an existing program. I have been programing VB for years. I had a problem when a program I ran the day before did not show Form1 at startup. I stripped out everything and in Form1.Load I put a sub with an OK message. Form1 had 2 labels. I started and saw the message but the form did not appear. The diagnosis graph kept running past 30 sec with no memory overload and nothing happening.
Previously I had 3 modules and 2 forms and a Class module. I comment out each in turn but no change then I deleted them and moved the subroutine to form1. with no result. also global break with the full program gave no result. No error messages just "OK Z". No debugging logs.
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadNames()
    End Sub


    Public Sub LoadNames()
        MsgBox("OK Z")
    End Sub

End Class


Did you take a look at the Windows Event Log?  WIN + R and enter eventvwr.exe.
Maybe there's an entry under Windows Logs -> Applications
